# How to find the rate of the Poisson process asociated with a continious Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, poisson-process

Suppose we are given the generator matrix Q of a continious, homogeneous  Markov chain X how do we find the Poisson process $N_t$, such that $Y_{N_t}=X_t$, where $Y$ denotes the jump chain. I know how to find the jump chain asociated with $X$ however, how to find the Poisson process, I do not. If possible, could you explain how to?

Comment: We can  only write $Y_{N_t}=X_t$ in the case where the holding times are exponentially distributed with a constant parameter, independent of the state.

Answer (score 1):

The transition function P(t) can be computed from the generator Q by solving a system of Kolmogorov forward or backward differential equations.
The Kolmogorov backward equation $P'(t) = QP(t)$ is a matrix equation, which bears a striking resemblance to the nonmatrix differential equation $p′(t) = qp(t)$, where $p$ is a differentiable function and $q$ is a constant. If $p(0) = 1$, the latter has the unique solution: $$p(t) =e^{tQ} \quad \text{for} \quad  t\geq0$$
If you are not familiar with solutions to matrix differential equations it might be
tempting to try to solve the backward equation by analogy, and write $$P(t) =e^{tQ} \quad (1)$$
since $P(0) = I.$

Given now that that you know matrix $Q$ and do the calculation in (1) you will obtain the transition matrix $P$.

\begin{align}
P_{ij}(t) &= \sum_{n=j-i}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!}Q_{ij}^{(n)}\\
&=\sum_{n=j-i}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!}\binom n{j-i} \lambda^n (-1)^{n-(j-i)}\\
&=\sum_{n=j-i}^\infty \frac{t^{j-i}}{(j-i)!}\lambda^{j-i}\frac{t^{n-(j-i)}}{(n-(j-i))!}(-\lambda)^{n-(j-i)}\\
&= \frac{(\lambda t)^{j-i}}{(j-i)!}\sum_{n=j-i}^\infty \frac{(-\lambda t)^{n-(j-i)}}{(n-(j-i))!}\\
&=\frac{(\lambda t)^{j-i}}{(j-i)!} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-\lambda t)^k}{k!}\\
&=\frac{(\lambda t)^{j-i}}{(j-i)!} e^{-\lambda t}.
\end{align}
As expected, the probability of transitioning from state $i$ to state $j$ (with $j\geqslant i$) in $(0,t]$ is the probability of there being $j-i$ arrivals in $(0,t]$.

Comment: I want to know how to determine the associated Poisson process, not the transition matrix.

Comment: in the transition matrix you will find the $\lambda$ parameter and given this you can describe the poisson process.I don't know what else you mean

Comment: I know how to find the transition matrix. You say I can find the parameter in the matrix, but where exactly. And more importantly, why does the parameter appear there.

Comment: @MathR I am deeply sorry if I am unable to answer your question.In the t.p.m the entries contain the $\lambda$ parameter.